# What is the grammatical term for is?

Tags: grammar, terminology

What is the grammatical term for "is"?
For example if the sentence is "Jane is Drawing", "Jane" is the Noun and "Drawing" is the verb, but what is "is"?

Comment: Hello, alphadev. This question would be better asked on the sister site, ELL. The verb (assuming it's accepted to be just a single verb) **be** has many different usages. Here, it is being used as an auxiliary (some might not even accept auxiliaries as verbs), linking with the [present participle](http://www.edufind.com/english/grammar/present_participle.php) (not noun here) 'drawing' to form the present continuous tense.

Comment: "Is drawing" is the present continuous (or present progressive) tense of verb to draw, in the third person singular.  However, as @EdwinAshworth mentioned above, this type of question would be better asked on ELL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the example sentence

> *Jane is drawing.*

"*Jane*" is indeed the **subject**, and
"*is drawing*" is the **predicate**.

Like many English predicates, it's composed of several verbs;
that's why it's called a **verb phrase,** rather than simply a verb.

The verb phrase "*is drawing*" is composed of two parts.

1. The last part, *drawing,* is the **main verb** (also called the matrix verb),
   and that's the part that tells  what the clause is about -- in this case, drawing (something).
   This particular main verb is in the *-ing* form, because it's part of the Progressive Construction.
2. The first part, *is*, is called an **auxiliary verb**.
   *Auxiliary* is a Latin term that means 'helping'. In grammar school,
   before students study Latin, teachers sometimes call these "helping verbs".
   This particular one is inflected for third person singular subject, present tense,
   and it's the first part of the Progressive Construction, which requires some form
   of the auxiliary verb *be*, followed immediately by an *-ing* verb form.

There are a lot of auxiliary verbs in English: *be, have, do, get,* etc.
Each one is used as a part of several constructions; auxiliary verbs don't have any meaning --
rather, they just serve to mark the particular construction, and that's the meaning.

More information on [Verb Phrases](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/VPguide.pdf) (and [the logic](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf) that underlies them) is available in the links.

Comment: I think it was in 'How Children Fail' that I read about a top educationalist astounding special-needs teachers with a demonstration of how they should be doing their job. If you're going to write an introductory grammar, my daughter Elizabeth is good with illustrations. _But I still prefer 'multi-word verb'_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Thank you, I think. The reason why ***I*** don't use "multi-word verb" is because it stretches the word "verb" to include "predicate", instead of retaining it as a lexical category. Also, it misses the possibility of making Verb Phrase, Noun Phrase, and Prepositional Phrase parallel in use and in sense. That's not good design.

Comment: It's based on the equivalence between say 'put on' [a coat] and 'don', 'take off' [from runway 2] and the French 'décoller'; and in other areas, 'ship of the desert' and 'camel', 'particle board' and 'particleboard', 'out of' [the window] and 'out', 'on top of' and 'atop' ... As you know. But I'll still record the counter-argument.

Answer (score 1):

“Is” is the third-person singular present-tense conjugation of the verb “be”.

The basic usage of “be” is as a [copula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_%28linguistics%29), as in “The sky **is** blue” or “I **am** your boss.”

However, in the sentence “Jane is drawing”, the “is” is a helping verb used in combination with the present participle (“ing”-suffixed form) of the main verb to form the [present continuous tense](http://www.edufind.com/english/grammar/present_continuous.php).

Comment: 'Basic' according to what criterion?

Answer (score 0):

"Is" is a helping verb which comes before verb. and it is used in present tense for singular subject.